# Ruby Object Comparable to Fixnum

Tags: ruby

I'd like to implement a class in Ruby that's comparable (using the `<=>` operator) with any Fixnum, *and vice-versa*. This will ultimately be used in a range. Here is an outline of my class:

```
class N
  include Comparable
  attr :offset
  def initialize(offset = 0)
    @offset = offset
  end
  def succ
    N.new(@offset + 1)
  end
  def +(offset)
    N.new(@offset + offset)
  end
  def <=>(other)
    return @offset <=> other.offset if other.kind_of? N
    return 1  # N is greater than everything else
  end
end

def n; N.new(0); end
```

Now this works great when used in `n..n+2` and `n..999`, but not in `1..n`. This is due to the fact that `n <=> 1` works but `1 <=> n` does not (returns ***nil***).

Is there any way I can get Fixnum to treat my N class as a comparable object? Your thoughts are appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to implement your own number type, you *must* implement `coerce`:

```
class N
  def coerce(other)
    return N.new(other), self
  end
end

n = N.new

1 <=> n # => -1
```

All of Ruby's builtin number types in the core library, all number types in the standard library, as well as all third-party number types use the `coerce` protocol to find a common type in order to make operators such as `+`, `*` and `==` commutative and `-`, `/` and `<=>` symmetric.

It's not quite clear to me what the semantics of `N` should be, so the above implementation is only an example.

Comment: Thanks Jörg, this is what I needed. I see now how it works and I can use it. The idea behind my `N` class was to denote the end of a range, so `(0..n)` is the whole range, `(0..n-1)` is everything except the last record, etc. So I'll change this example a bit, but the idea is great.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did a little monkey patching (*freedom* patching ;) that seems to have solved my problem for now.

```
class Fixnum
  def <=>(other)
    return -1 if other.kind_of? N
    return -1 if self < other
    return 0 if self == other
    return 1 if self > other
  end
end
```

Output seems to be as expected and it doesn't break anything in the inner workings of `Fixnum` as far as I can tell. Any better ideas/comments, feel free to post 'em.

```
1 <=> n # => -1
1 <=> 1 # => 0
1 <=> 2 # => -1
2 <=> 1 # => 1
1 == 1  # => true
1 == 2  # => false
1 < 2   # => true
1 > 2   # => false
```

Comment: `return N <=> self if other.kind_of? N`

Comment: Yuck. *If* you absolutely *must* monkey patch, you should *at least* ensure to not break the public contract of the method.

Comment: Haha, desperate times call for desperate measures ;)